# Retrieve custom table data

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, database, postgresql

I have a scenario, where I have three tables `custom_tables`, `custom_fields` and `custom_field_values` on which multiple filtering condition will be applied on values stored in `custom_field_values`. We have `entity_id` in `custom_field_values` which is the unique identifier to identify each row, in simple word `entity_id` is representing a single row in normal tables. Here is the table with the example,

[image] [image] [image]

Now, I have condition which says `age > 25`, in this case it is only remove the 3rd row in `custom_field_values` table whereas I want to remove whole records with same `entity_id` example in `custom_field_values` 3rd rows is not true according to our condition, and its entity_id is `12345`, so i want to unselect all the record with this `entity_id` and I am expecting result something like this,

[image]

**I am having trouble achieving this, I am looking for some generic and fastest way to achieve this as custom tables can have more than 1 millions records, can anyone help... please...**

Answer (score 0):

This is ***a terrible design***, and no matter what you do it will not be fast, especially with the number of rows you expect,  and maintenance will be a nightmare and error prone. Your best bet is to redesign to wind up with 1 table. Since I have no idea what the function custom_tables table serves, I'' just use the others. So with just the other 2 you would have:

```
create table custom_tables (
             id            bigserial 
           , entity_id     text        -- or integer/bigint if appropriate
           , name          text
           , age           integer
           ) ;
```

If you stay with this (nonsensical) design then at least create a view that essentially maps to the above table; or better a materialized view as follows:

```
create or replace view custom_tables_set as
   with id_fld as 
         ( select cfv.entity_id, cfv.value id
              from custom_field_values cfv
              left join custom_fields  cf  on(cf.id = cfv.custom_field_id)
             where cf.alias = 'id'
          ) 
       , name_fld as
         ( select cfv.entity_id, cfv.value as name 
              from custom_field_values cfv
              left join custom_fields  cf  on(cf.id = cfv.custom_field_id)
             where cf.alias = 'name'
          )  
       , age_fld as  ( select cfv.entity_id, cfv.value age  
              from custom_field_values cfv
              left join custom_fields  cf  on(cf.id = cfv.custom_field_id)
             where cf.alias = 'age'
          )  
   select i.entity_id, i.id, n.name, a .age 
     from id_fld  i 
     left join name_fld n on n.entity_id = i.entity_id
     left join age_fld  a on a.entity_id = i.entity_id ;
```

You will need to add other .._fld CTE for every alias value you create.  
At least with the view you will not the join(s) on every query you write.

Good Luck!